# How many possible line segments can be found in a collinear line with an x number of points?

Tags: geometry

**What would be the method or the formula for this kinds of problems/equations?**

A given example would be:

How many possible line segments can be formed in a collinear line  with 6 points? What is the used formula?

Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: Pick any two of 6 endpoints. $\binom{6}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

For every one of your $x$ points, you have $x-1$ alternatives when choosing a partner to form a line segment. But that way you count every segment twice, once in one and once in the opposite direction. Therefore your total count is

$$\frac{x\cdot(x-1)}2=\binom{x}{2}$$

The latter notation is called a [binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient), and is the established notation for tasks of the kind “choose $k$ objects from a total of $n$, without putting them back (so all $k$ objects are distinct) and without regard to order”.